# Adjusting the bar form center point to the left point

Tags: ios-charts

When a bar chart is drawn, we set the width (or use the default value) and use the center point in the dataset.  I am trying to create a bar chart that will use the point set as the left point and the bar width will go to the next point.

So, for example, right now my dataset is like this:
(0.0,0.5),(5.0, 1.0), (10.0, 0.5), (11.0,1.0)

And the bar chart is like this:

```
       **        **
       **        **
**     **     ** **
**     **     ** **
```

What I would like it to look like is like this:

```
     *****     *
     *****     *
****************
****************
```

I see that my problem is twofold.  First the point of the bar is a center point.  I need it to be the left corner of the top of the bar.  Second the bar width is a set width.  I need it to stop at the next point on the chart.

I did not post code here because I think it will be in the configuration, but I am not sure where to turn (I have reviewed the documentation and can not find anything).

Any ideas or suggestions to point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Please add some code related to DataSet you are passing and Chart setup so can get an idea what you have done so far and how we can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: could you show an image of the chart result you are getting?